# Multiple group by with aggregate in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008

I currently have this code:

```
foreach (var newsToPolitician in news.NewsToPoliticians)
{
     var politician = newsToPolitician.Politician;
     var votes = (from s in db.Scores
                   where o.IDPolitician == politician.IDPolitician
                         && o.IDNews == IDNews
                   group o by o.IDAtribute
                   into g
                   select new{
                      Atribute= g.Key,
                      TotalScore= g.Sum(x => x.Score)
                   }).ToList();
}
```

It works alright, but I want to avoid making multiple queries to my database in `foreach` loop.
My table `Scores` looks like this:

```
IDScore | IDNews | IDUser | IDPolitician | IDAtribute | Score
1         40       1010     35             1             1
2         40       1010     35             2            -1
3         40       1002     35             1             1
4         40       1002     35             2             1
5         40       1002     40             1            -1
...
```

My goal is to aggregate all the scores for all politicians in a news. A news can have up to 7 politicians.
Is it expensive to call my database up to seven times in a `foreach` loop. I know that isn't best practice so I'm interested is there any way to avoid it in this particular case and make one call to database and then process it on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update - Due to user comments have re-jigged to try and ensure aggregation on the server.
In this case we can group on the server by both `IDPolitician` and `IDAttribute` and then pull the groups in with `ToLookup` locally as so:

```
var result = db.Scores.Where(s => s.IDNews == IDNews)
                      .Where(s => news.NewsToPoliticians
                                      .Select(n => n.Politician.IDPolitician)
                                      .Contains(s.IDPolitician))
                      .GroupBy(s => new
                                    {
                                      s.IDPolitician,
                                      s.IDAttribute
                                    },
                                (k,g ) => new
                                          {
                                           k.IDPolitician,
                                           k.IDAttribute,
                                           Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Score)
                                           })
                      .ToLookup(anon => anon.IDPolitician,
                                anon => new { anon.IDAttribute, anon.Sum })
```

Legacy - 
You want to use `GroupJoin` here, it would be something along the lines of:

```
var result = news.NewsToPoliticians
                 .GroupJoin( db.Scores.Where(s= > s.IDNews == IDNews),
                             p => p.IDPolitician,
                             s => s.IDPolitician,
                             (k,g) => new
                                      {
                                        PoliticianId = k,
                                        GroupedVotes = g.GroupBy(s => s.IDAtribute,
                                                                 (id, group) => new
                                                                                {
                                                                                 Atribute = id,
                                                                                 TotalScore = group.Sum(x => x.Score)
                                                                                 })
                                      })
                 .ToList();
```

However you are at the mercy of your provider as to how it translates this so it might still be multiple queries to get round this you could use something like:

```
var politicianIds = news.NewsToPoliticians.Select(p => p.IDPolitician).ToList()
var result = db.Scores.Where(s= > s.IDNews == IDNews)
                      .Where(s => politicianIds.Contains(s.IDPolitician))
                      .GroupBy(p => p.IDPolitician,
                              (k,g) => new
                                       {
                                        PoliticianId = k,
                                        GroupedVotes = g.GroupBy(s => s.IDAtribute,
                                                                 (id, group) => new
                                                                                {
                                                                                 Atribute = id,
                                                                                 TotalScore = group.Sum(x => x.Score)
                                                                                 })
                                       })
                      .ToList();
```

Which hopefully should be at most 2 query (depending on whether `NewsToPoliticians` is db dependent). You'll just have to try it out and see.

Comment: @ttkalec no probs, have added another edit in case `GroupJoin` is being mapped to a foreach in your provider which should hopefully get round that.

Comment: This actually doesn't work. I profiled it and it translates it into simple `SELECT` and then aggregates it on server side. I want to use SQL to aggregate it, so I guess that I'll need to use Stored Procedures after all.

Comment: @ttkalec Have re-jigged it, this should be one query, if its not then its probably time to change provider...

Comment: Whoa! This is a great piece of code, and exactly what I've needed. Thank you for your time and effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a stored procedure and get the SQL server engine to do all the work. You can still use Linq to call the stored procedure and this will minimize all the calls to the database

Comment: I'd create a view to do the hard/work and then map it to an entity

Comment: Stored procedures are nicer than views for future edits, you can add these to the DBML designer to update, being the result will ensure your result will be strongly defined it will not affect your code

Comment: I can't see how SPs are better for future edits. What if you're using code-first?

Comment: Stored procedures work fine with my problem, but adds additional complications with translating results back to entities, and further grouping by IDPolitician.